# Frequency response and phase response

Tags: power-electronics, filter, high-pass-filter

In filters there is frequency response and phase response but why we consider these two parameters.

1. What is the significance of these responses in practical applications?
2. In Bessel filters, after referring a document say that it has phase to frequency relationship is quite linear, what is it means?

Explanation by practical approach is easier to understand.

Comment: *but why we consider these two parameters* <-- when we use or design a filter, we are doing so because we want to adjust the frequency response of a signal hence, we consider the frequency response because it's a fundamental part of how the filter performs.

Answer (score 0):

It means that if you input a sine wave to filter, the filter changes the sine wave. The amplitude will be different compared to the original sine wave. The phase will be different to the original sine wave. For example you can calculate how much a basic RC filter changes the amplitude and phase for a given frequency you feed into it.

The phase change can also be understood that the filter has delayed the signal in time domain.

Bessel filters have a property that they don't change the phase or delay the signal much in the passband, so it does not change waveform shape but only amplitude.